# Batch file to check two file sizes great than 1KB, if not runn command

Tags: batch-file

i am quite new to coding so please bear with me :)

I am looking to create Batch file to do the following:

1)check two file sizes are greater than 1KB

2)if they are not then run a command (which updates the files)

3)check files again to see if they are are greater than 1KB, if not greater than 1KB run command again

4)if they are greater than 1kb then stop

any help is appreciated

thank you

Comment: your requirements are ambigous. Show us what you tried and ask the exact questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

REM The two file names are the first and second parameters to the batch file

:CheckFileSizes
if %~z1 LEQ 1024 (
    if %~z2 LEQ 1024 (
        REM add your logic here!
        echo TEST >> %1
        echo TEST >> %2

        rem Recheck the file sizes
        goto :CheckFileSizes
    )
)

goto :EOF
```

Comment: Getting the file size is much simpler, read `help set` and try `%~z1`. OP question is not about the difference in size but to the size of the two files.

Comment: +1, - I never noticed the `/-C` option before, I like that. But there is a much easier way to get the file size: Use the `~z` modifier. If you have a parameter then just `%~z1`. If no parameter then `for %%F in ("fileName") do set fileSize=%%~zF`

Answer (score 0):

One way using a `bash` script:

```
for i in *; do

    FILESIZE=$(stat -c %s "$i")

    while [ $FILESIZE -lt 1024 ]; do

         echo "appending text" >> $i

         FILESIZE=$(stat -c %s "$i")

         if [ $FILESIZE -ge 1024 ]; then
             break
         fi
    done
done
```

Comment: +1 Not because related to the OP question, but because related to the situation on another platform / language.